# Browser sync with proxy option is it possible to pass IP Address Range?

Tags: web-application

Is it possible to use browser-sync with proxy option with Ip Address Range (or) comma separated list of Ip Address
browser-sync start --proxy "10.1.1.15-25"
something the one i have mentioned here is it possible?

Comment: Which browser? Are you writing an application or trying to get a feature to work on a web site?

Comment: I am not writing any feature i am actually trying to use browser-syn application to ease my application Testing process my requirement is simple i need to Test our Internal application with all the browser's as a part of Testing.I just wanted to if we can pass subdomain (or) IP range for Proxy option that is available

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to make this question more clear. Beginning with the info you've given in the comment above, and then giving us more information on the application you're trying to use, how it's configured, and any errors it's returning.